# SAS Error: Open Code Statement Recursion detected

Tags: sas, macros

Just getting an error msg on the following code:

```
%let start=1;
%let end=6;

%global i;
%put note: &start, &end;

/*Print i*/
%do i=&start %to &end;

    %put note: &i

%end;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're missing a semicolon in your loop: `%put note: &i;`. You also need to encapsulate your loop within a macro.

```
%macro loop;
    %let start=1;
    %let end=6;
    
    %global i;
    %put note: &start, &end;
    
    /*Print i*/
    %do i=&start %to &end; 
    
        %put note: &i;
    
    %end;
%mend;
%loop;
```

```
note: 1, 6
note: 1
note: 2
note: 3
note: 4
note: 5
note: 6
```

Comment: Thanks! I thought that, as %if %then %do, the "DO-WHILE" may also work outside the macro definition. Thanks!